# Wordpress REST API custom endpoint for method POST

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, rest

I am currently working on a project which requires a WordPress website and a simple REST api. I discovered that WordPress has its own REST api and decided to extend its functionality to meet my needs. All I need to do is to have endpoints for GET and POST requests that retrieve/insert data from/to a table which is not directly related to WordPress (but in the same database). I successfully implemented all GET requests, however, I am struggling to get the POST ones working.
I have this route register defined:

```
register_rest_route('api/v1', 'create-player/', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'create_player',
));
```

The client sends a request through ajax call which is expected to hit the endpoint from the route above. This is the ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
       method: "POST",
       url: '/wp-json/api/v1/create-player/',
       data : JSON.stringify(data),
       contentType: 'applcation/json',
       beforeSend: function (xhr){
           xhr.setRequestHeader("X-WP-None", locData.nonce);
           console.log('beforeSend');
       },
       success: function(response){
           console.log("success" + response);
       },
       fail: function (response){
           console.log("fail" + response);
       }
    });
```

I am not sure how to build the POST route register from the REST api, the other GET requests have an attribute `args` that map directly to the parameters passed in the endpoint. Do I need something like that to handle the request data when using POST? How do I get the data type passed from the ajax and then use it in my function `create_player();` The WP REST API documentation seems to be incomplete and all of the information I found uses endpoints for built-in WordPress features such as posts/authors/blogs etc. but I don't need that, I just want to use the provided functionality and create my own interface. Thank you.

Comment: FYI, there's nothing REST about that API.

Comment: @Evert Okay, I understand that the POST and GET methods are not under the same endpoint (in this case for /player) and having a "more restful" api is exactly what I am trying to achieve. In the example above I separated the POST method from the other endpoints to make my question clearer. Although I was not able to understand how the WP REST API POST requests work, I managed to implement a silly workaround by passing a JSON to the url when sending a POST request, this way I can get the actual data and manipulate it. But I would still love to understand how to handle this situation properly...

Comment: I can't help you much with wordpress, but if you are interested in developing better REST apis, I'd recommend you read this: https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html if you are not 'Level 3' you are technically not REST.

Comment: Your request has a misspelling in the contentType param for $.ajax call.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally found it! In order to access the body of the POST request use `$request->get_body();` in your `register_rest_route` callback method.

Comment: Sir, I want to use "post method" in custom end point by using "register_rest_route". Because I want to get the current logged in user in wordpress from app. How can I do this Sir?

Answer (score 15):

in your callback function you can use something like this:

```
 $param = $request->get_param( 'some_param' );

  // You can get the combined, merged set of parameters:
 $parameters = $request->get_params();
```

https://www.coditty.com/code/wordpress-api-custom-route-access-post-parameters

Answer (score 1):

Add POST in methods while registering route and in your callback function access your POST variables via `$request` array. That's it.